# Dealing with file locks from read-only users

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, access, lock

At work, our team publishes a file, which we make available on Sharepoint (O365) with a fixed (permanent) filename and direct URL.  We are the only ones with edit access to the file, but a few dozen people have been granted direct, read-only access to the file.  Every night we upload the latest version of the file to Sharepoint, replacing the file, so people can always access the latest one via the same direct link.

However we are starting to get errors from the upload script such as:

`The file <URL> is locked for exclusive use by someuser@example.com [membership]`

In this example, "someuser" has read-only access to the file.  However, if he opens the file and forgets and leaves it open overnight, we cannot upload a new copy of the file because of his lock.

How can we deal with this?  If this happened once or twice, we could perhaps reach out to the user, but this can potentially break our automation any time.  If a user with read-only access has locking rights over the file which can potentially prevent us from uploading a new version, then we need a different solution that will still provide users with a direct link to the latest file.  (We are not administrators of the corporate O365/Sharepoint system, only administrators of our own site)

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,  end users only need to have the permission to view file, I will suggest you to use a [**File view web part**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c) to display the document content in a modern page. You can use a static URL for the page, and viewing the page will not disturb the process of editing files.

Comment: Jerry, I'm not sure how to do that with a CSV file under the "Documents" section of Sharepoint.  I want users to be able to have a direct link to view and (importantly) download the file, the way they would with Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, etc.  The method you're describing sounds like embedding it in a web page - is that correct?

Comment: @DavidWhite Yes, it is a web part in a web page. And for file viewer web part, you can easily download the file. As for csv files it will be opened in read-only mode in excel, save  as and other basic functions are available.